# Online store in drupal

Tags: drupal

Which modules can be used for creating an online store in drupal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say the most popular module for an online store in Drupal is the [ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) module. It's quite complex, but supports pretty much everything you need for an online store. Here's the supported feature list:

- Configurable product catalog includes catalog pages and a block to display product categories.
- Flexible product creation system with product classes.
- Multiple product image support out of the box.
- Flexible product attributes system.
- Basic product stock level tracking and notification.
- Product features to add file downloads, role promotions, and more to products.
- Single page checkout.
- Automatic account generation (anonymous checkout).
- Customer and administrator checkout notifications.
- Simple order processing (with workflow-ng integration for automated order processing).
- Simple order creation and editing.
- Integrated payment system that acts as a bridge between acceptable payment methods -(check, credit card, purchase order, etc.) and payment gateways (Cyber Source, Authorize.net, PayPal, etc.).
- Shipping quotes and fulfillment, including integration with UPS, FedEx, USPS.
- Sales, product, and customer reports.
- Activity logging.

Comment: I agree, few of my friends have fully working ecommerce websites based on ubercart.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7, you also have the [Commerce module](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) that looks very promising and fully integrates with Drupal's API and core features (Entity, Fields, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get started with an online store based on Drupal. This is a great starting point. http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart 
It is based on Drupal commerce and has some really nice features included, like a mobile optimized theme, slideshow, great admin theme for ecommerce, ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Drupal commerce. [Drupal commerce](http://www.valuebound.com/blog/drupal-commerce-right-choice-your-online-store) is an open source eCommerce solution built on top of drupal. Also it has numerous useful modules which can meet all your ecommerce requirements. Also you can build online stores of small to large size.

These are some of the features of drupal commerce and it contains specific modules for these.

- Create product types with custom attributes
- Order management
- line item
- Payment method API
- Tax calculation / VAT support
- Discount pricing rules/coupon

U.K postal service Royal mail, international language school Eurocentres, McDonalds France and lot more consumer brands are the most trusted clients who strongly believes in the power of Drupal commerce